# Should I prefer to use eventaggregator in domain objects?

Tags: domain-driven-design, prism

After reading many articles on Prism. I am still confused!!

I am trying to create an application whose domain object will be completely independent of GUI. User can interact with application from command line also. So totally decoupled. I am trying to make independent componenets of domain objects which can talk with each other using some events. How should I implement this?

Should I prefer to use event aggregator in domain objects? There are few posts for same but none of them give me a satisfactory answer.

If no then what is best way to achieve the same feature in domain objects.

Comment: @Cuong Le - Thanks for editing it. Next time I will not say thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the event aggregator in Prism for domain objects because it is intended for  UI events. If you would like to have similar behavior in your domain model, you should use [domain events](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/04/08/strengthening-your-domain-domain-events/). Effectively, the event aggregator is replaced by a domain event publisher.

Comment: great thanks.. but I am interested to know what is difference between these two.

Comment: they are very similar in nature - to decouple publishers from subscribers. their implementations differ to address constraints of the environments for which they were designed. for example, the event aggregator in prism uses [weak references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx) for subscriptions which aren't needed for a domain event publishers because those are usually scoped by a unit of work.